# Retrieve Variable From Class

Tags: python, class, variables, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am trying to get the text variable from a `QLineEdit` widget that is created in a function within a class. Usually I would specify the class in which the variable was created for ex. `var = classname.variable` but this doesn't work in this case since the variable is created in a function in a class. Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 150)

        line = QLineEdit(self)
        line.resize(100, 21)
        line.move(10, 35)
        line.setText("the coolest text")

        self.show()



text = main.line.text()
print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How can I get this variable without putting all my code in one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 270, 150)

        self.line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.resize(120, 21)
        self.line.move(83, 35)
        self.line.setText("the coolest text")

        self.show()

# text = main.line.text()
# print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)                # +
    gui = main()
#    app = QApplication

    text = gui.line.text()                      # +
    print(text)    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]